# Storing variables for other pages in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a PHP project and I made a registration form.
In the registration form, I made three steps,
the data will be stored in the third step, but in the third step the variables
that I stored from the page 1 is disappeared!!

What shall I do?

Comment: How are you storing the variables? Show us example code. Use cookies.

Comment: Use `cookies` or `session`.

Comment: i mean with 'Storing' that the data will be inserted to the database .. Dimme, your answer is useful thanks

Comment: Rikesh, Thanks also ... :)

Comment: Have you tried google? https://www.google.no/search?q=php+multipage+form&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:nb-NO:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

Comment: Don't down vote the question. It can be a new era for him to learn something new...

Comment: @OhWhatANoob that made me laugh

Comment: @Joshua, Yes, you can laugh there

Comment: @OhWhatANoob , seems your name is calling me hhhhh

Comment: @KimozerAljithr,  my name refers to myself. I am a noob coder..:(

Comment: All of you here were like me . Don't laugh then :)<br>i'm new at php thats why

Comment: @OhWhatANoob, so many comments and answers are there, still no improvement in the question asked.

Comment: I am still a naive coder, all pro coder were once a noob in their life too

Comment: @KimozerAljithr, please go through the faq here : http://stackoverflow.com/faq as to what type of questions can be asked and how - which no one in this post suggested.

Comment: @Istiaque I had a problem, i asked , then i got the answer . I guess this is the objective of StackOverflow . Thanks :)

Comment: @KimozerAljithr, actually the question does not seem to be much clear. 1) '..stored from the page 1 is disappeared' - number of pages not mentioned. 2) A form is likely to be placed in a single page. Is that page 1 or step 1?No code snippet provided to understand the situation. The SO FAQ is enough to help anyone understand the asking pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session, post or get method inorder to pass the data from one page to another page.

Answer (score 2):

Now it's time for you to learn PHP `sessions`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Using PHP session you can preserve certain data across subsequent accesses.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Sessions in the PHP docs. Especially `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

The things which are missed by you are:

- Not maintaining the single session of the all pages kindly put the session_start(); on every page to maintain the single session
- For storing the variable using the $_SESSION[$variable_name] = $value to dynamically store the value and use on any page and to know about session follow the [link here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

I had a few problems with sessions, though they do appear to be just what you're looking for. Here's an alternative if you should need it:

If you need backward compatibility and the first two two pages don't contain any "private" data, you could use some posting system to send the info to the next page, but be warned this opens up an entry point for anyone trying to inject into your database, make sure you strip slashes and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Save all first page post values in to session as like $_SESSION['page']=$_POST when clicking secon page,and store second page post values also when clicking third page ,save all the third page post values in session,Finally you get all values from session.

Answer (score 0):

If you use form button to go steps. You can puth hidden inputs han recive the data in $_POST['data1'], $_POST['data2'], ...

Answer (score 0):

Use SESSION, and read the data from session in your third page and unset the SESSION